# Ticket Selling Problem in REST with django

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am doing a project where we run into a problem, where we have `N` number of tickets available at certain time. And we are serving it from the backend REST API and people are buying it in FIFO fashion. Its like a race between the buyers.

#### Problem:

Currently we are handling it like first we take the money from the user (we take money first because it is might possible that customer's bank transaction fails due to some reason so we make it confirm we do not lose anything) and the proceed for the conformation email but we faced the Overbooking issue. Because we already had taken the money but there was no tickets available because in the meanwhile someone else bought it. So we have to give that customer tickets, which lead us to over booking.

I want to solve it. I have put some thoughts on it.

#### First Solution:

The first solution I come up with is that I have an API that will initially check whether enough tickets are available to sell, if it is, it subtract the number of tickets from the available tickets and ask the customer for payment. Once the payment get confirmed we send customer confirmation email. If it fails we will add those subtracted tickets to the number of available tickets. It apparently seems working but It has some flaws.

For example we may lose the tickets permanently, in case user decide not to make any bank transaction or his browser crashes etc.

#### Second Solution:

Second solution is to use Django session that will save the information temporarily by subtracting the number of tickets user buying from the tickets available once the the we get the confirmation we will commit the the data base transaction. if not we can roll back. I believe it will break the RESTful API stateless property.

#### Question:

Do we have any standard way to solve this problem? I have searched over internet I did not find any solution, and do let me know if this problem is know from another name and already have a standard solution that can be used as is. If not then please share you knowledge and experience.

Comment: Maybe introduce the concept of "reserved" tickets where you reserve a ticket for a user for a certain amount of time (e.g. 10 minutes) before they pay and confirm it after they have. If they haven't paid after 10 minutes, let the user know that the ticket has been unreserved again and make it available for other users to reserve.

Comment: @DMalan I have this in my mind, but I am confused, where to store the reserved information? In django sessions or database?

Comment: Probably database.

Comment: How can you please elaborate it?

Comment: Can you post your database structure or Django models? I have no idea what your current setup is.

Comment: currently there is `Event` and event has number of available  tickets. and then there is `EventBooking`, that stores the information about the user, as soon as `EventBooking` created(validation is done whether related Event has enough tickets available or not if available it send email otherwise throw error in response) , and sending confirmation email task starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering this late, but I was manage to solve this problem. To solve the issue, I used django signals. It was two step procedure.

First of all I added states in `Transaction` states, which was `confirmed, cancelled, reserved, expired`.

1. User will call the `/reserve` endpoint this will create a transaction which will subtract tickets, but in `reserved` state. It will subtract the number of reserved tickets from the available tickets of an event. `on_create` signal will initiate a `celery` task, which will run lets say after 5 minutes, so after 5 minutes it will add those tickets back if they are expired.
2. User will come to next step where he will confirm the transaction from end point `/purchase`. So now we will mark the transaction in `confirmed` state.

There was a `/cancel` endpoint which will explicitly cancel the tickets.

This had downside that someone may abuse the system by keeping the tickets in reserved state (obliviously that's rare case).